# How can i sort an HashMap in Kotlin by timestamp from a class?

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a class like this

```
class Message(val id: String, val text: String, val id_sender:String, val id_receiver:String, val datatime:Long){}
```

and an HashMap with this class as value:

```
val map = HashMap<String, Message>()
```

The `map` has already some elements. How can i sort it by `datatime`?

Answer (score 2):

> How can I sort a HashMap?

That's impossible; hashmaps are unordered constructs.

You can sort a Map, perhaps - Map is the common supertype and it makes no claims of orderability of the map (HashMap is a Map, and it has no order. It makes no sense to talk about 'the first entry in a hashmap'. e.g. TreeMap is also a Map and it has an order. It DOES make sense to talk about the 'first entry' of a TreeMap).

In general sorting a map (any map, any type, as long as it is a subtype of j.u.Map) on an aspect of the value is impossible. You can sort on key though (TreeMap does that, automatically. A TreeMap is sorted on key, always, continuously - you can't have it be unsorted at any time).

Thus, whatever made you go: "I know! I'll just have a map, but, you know, sorted. On the `getTimestamp()` property of the Message object, which is the value" - that was not the right answer. As you didn't explain why you think you needed that there's not much more I can say.

One solution could be that you make a `TreeSet<Message>` object and put your messages in, and give that TreeSet a custom comparator that sorts first on timestamp then on message ID (Note that TreeSet, TreeMap and friends use ONLY the comparator, not equals/hashCode, at all - so if 2 different messages have the same timestamp and you compare solely on timestamp, that doesn't work. Hence why you should make a dual comparator.

You can make these easily, these days (this is java, not kotlin, but should translate fairly easily):

```
SortedSet<Message> messages = new TreeSet<>(Comparator
  .comparing(Message::getTimestamp)
  .thenComparingLong(Message::getMessageId));
```

You can also make a `TreeMap`, but, remember: That sorts **on key**, not on value. It can't sort on value.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm trying to create a chat log, where the latest messages with the various users are displayed (as in whatsapp or telegram) and the messages are sorted by timestamp. I used a HashMap to store messages simply because the key matches the user's id, so when it is received / sent by that particular user the corresponding value in the hashmap is changed. But since sorting with this method is not possible I have to think of another option.

Comment: You can keep your data structure for holding your data and only sort the messages for display. For display you may for example put all the messages into a list and sort it.